# text-indent not working into <span> <li> children

Tags: html, css

I am applying few styles into my `<li>` but the weird part this style is not working inside the tag `<span>` , I thought my styles defined in the parent li will apply in all children am I right?

someone can explain me why? thanks.

**css:**

```
.days li a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.days li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.days li {
  background-color: black;
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-weight: 220;
  width: 300px;
}

.days li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<ul class="days">
  <li><a href="">January 3, 2016 <br><span> Day 01</span></a></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016
    <br><span>january 01</span></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016
    <br><span>february 01</span></li>
</ul>
```

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/3mesf9g7/

Comment: The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block

Comment: Try this: .days li span { display:block; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `spans` to inherit the `text-indent` you have tu set `display:block`, not possible in inline elements

Comment: thanks, look this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mesf9g7/1/ , what I whant is make the hover in the hole block, right now is not working because i have padding, any ideas how to fix this? thanks again.

Comment: Not sure why you left out the part mentioned in your comment. IMO, that's the answer. It works with `display: block` only because `text-indent` is an inherited property and so `span` inherits it from the parent.

Comment: @Raduken you can put the :hover in the li: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/3mesf9g7/2/

Comment: @Harry, you are right, my comment was the answer to the question but I suppose he needed a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.days li a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.days li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.days li {
  background-color: black;
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-weight: 220;
  width: 300px;
}

.days li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="days">
  <li><a href="">January 3, 2016 <br><span> Day 01</span></a></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016
    <br><span>january 01</span></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016
    <br><spa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.days li a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.days li a:hover {
  text-decoration: normal;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.days li {
  background-color: black;
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-weight: 220;
  width: 300px;
}

.days li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
  display:block;
}
</style>
<ul class="days">
  <li><a href="">January 3, 2016 <br><span> Day 01</span></a></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016
    <br><span>january 01</span></li>
  <li>January 3, 2016</li>
  </ul>
```

This also work .this code is correct or not